# Very strange issue in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I really can't understand why i get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in the line where I assign `NSArray *topLevelObjects`. It's crazy because I use exactly the same code and the same BlogCell in another `tabliView`, and there it's working perfectly!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int r = indexPath.row;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Blog";
    BlogCell *cell = (BlogCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlogCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];  
    }        

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all the outlets you specify in BlogCell to FilesOwner have corresponding IBOutlets in this class.

Comment: Every outlet is connected, but to the UITableViewCell, not to FilesOwner. And it works perfectly in the other tableView